# Why isn't this PosgreSQL LIKE query working?

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.2.

```
[local] postgres@host=# select * from units where ip_address LIKE '192.168.43.%';
ERROR:  42883: operator does not exist: inet ~~ unknown
 LINE 1: select * from units where ip_address LIKE '192.168.43.%';
                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  op_error, parse_oper.c:722
Time: 0.309 ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12):

The error message clearly describes the problem: "operator does not exist: inet ~~ unknown"

So you should use the [native operators for `inet` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-net.html).

In your case it should be

```
... where ip_address << '192.168.43/24'::inet;
```

where the value after the slash specifies the number of significant bits in the value (24 bits = 3 bytes = x.y.z.any). For example `192.168.128/17` means any address from `192.168.128.0` to `192.168.255.255`.

---

You can convert an `inet` value into `varchar` and deal with it like with any other varchar but it will break any benefits from the original type and disallow indexes if any. However, here is example:

```
... where ip_address::varchar like '192.168.43.%/32';
```

Additionally it may provide the wrong result if `ip_address` value is partially qualified in the way mentioned above (for example if `ip_address = '192.168/16'` it is not like `'192.168.1.%'` which is generally wrong because '192.168/16' value holds anything from '192.168.0.0' to '192.168.255.255')